# Need to get route change notification for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

Need to handle event with hands free(ear phone). It is not working with .AVAudioSessionRouteChange. Please suggest. Here is how observer added:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handleRouteChange),
                                           name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange,
                                           object: AVAudioSession.sharedInstance())
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik: Shared here. How observer is added to call specific method.

Comment: is not working in foreground or else (background or suspended)

Comment: It is not working foreground when plug in the ear phone and use its button to play and pause.

Comment: try one on play and pause state `var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers)
try? audioS`

Comment: var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers)
try? audioSession.setActive(true)

Comment: @Anbu.karthik: Thanks for your hints, but still that is not working.

Comment: something missed in the code,